# "Oh Yeah" or "Oh, Yeah"?

Tags: commas, interjections

I read that every interjection should be separated from the sentence, no matter where it's placed, with a comma. If that's true, would phrases such as these require a comma after "*oh*"?

> *"Oh yeah" or "oh, yeah"?*
>
> *"Oh my God" or "oh, my God"?*

I feel as if the phrases "*oh yeah*" and "*oh my god*" are both treated as interjections and that they shouldn't need a comma after the "*oh.*" Am I wrong, or is there a rule to this?

Answer (score 3):

First off, that sounds like a [made up grammar rule](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/03/7-grammar-myths-you-learned-in-school/), so I wouldn't worry about it too much either way.

But to your question, you can insert or not insert the comment depending on what effect you want to convey.

Putting a comma in there could make it sound like there is a slight pause after "oh". You might want to omit the comma if you want it to sound like Bob in the Bob's Burgers clip Andrew posted. That is, with no pause.

Either way, it really doesn't matter much

Comment: I agree; this boils down to whether the expression _Oh my god_ is treated as single interjection, or two combined. In the end, I think the phrase gets used often enough that the grammar police wouldn't get upset about a comma omission.

Answer (score 2):

The comma is not usually used when writing either expression.  When speaking you can of course insert any pause or use any intonation you want.

Example: [500 different ways to say "Oh my god"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFr-kNbXHew)